# How to design database schema for meteor/mondodb for this situation?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, meteor, database-schema

I don't know how the collection for a meteor app should be.
In MySQL I would have 3 tables:

- table_1: id, column_a, column_b
- table_2: id, table_1_id, column_c, column_d
- table_3: id, column_e, column_f

table_2 and table_3 could have the same identical rows. Some information can be in both tables, in table_2 and not in table_3, in table_3 and not in table_2.

I know that in meteor/mongodb when you design database schema, you need to know how you will access/display the information. I want to display something like this:

- table_1.column_a
- show all rows from table2 where table_2.table_1_id=table_1.id; and I
  also want to check if table_2.column_c=table_3.column_e, if it's true
  than I want to display that row from table_3.

I hope you understand, also if you have some suggestions about subscriptions/publications would be much appreciated.

P.S. I am sorry for the title of this topic, but I couldn't find a more specific title.

**UPDATE:**

Explaining it above I better understand the problem.

What I want is like a list of products(list A), and every product has a list of specifications. And I would like to have another list(list B), where I have a list of specifications with more details.
And I want to display the product details, including it's list of specifications, and when it displays the specifications of the products, I want to search in list B to find if there is a similar item, to show it's full descriptions.
I want to make that search when it's displaying because I want to be able to add the specification details(list B) later and this list will be updated periodically.
The list A(title, and another 3-4 columns) would have tens of thousands of products, the list of specification(title) of products in list A would have 10-20 items, and list B(title, description, status) would have a few hundreds.

I have an idea to create a collection of list A and for every product in there add an array with the specifications, and another collection for list B. I would subscribe/publish the whole collection of list B, and when I display the list A, I would search for every specification in list B. I don't know how good this idea is.

Comment: without giving an ER model you aren't going to get a good answer.

Comment: @George I'd recommend rewriting this question with the simplest example with real names that you can think of. The publishers portion of the question is too broad - ask this as a separate, more narrow version after getting an answer to this one.